# Why is regex failing when input contains a newline?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've inherited this javascript regex from another developer and now, even though nothing has changed, it doesn't seem to match the required text. Here is the regex:

```
/^.*(already (active|exists|registered)).*$/i
```

I need it to match any text that looks like

> stuff stuff already exists more stuff etc

It looks perfectly fine to me, it only looks for those 2 words together and should in theory ignore the rest of the string. In my script I check the text like this

```
var cardUsedRE = /^.*(already (active|exists|registered)).*$/i;
if(cardUsedRE.test(responseText)){
    mdiv.className = 'userError';
    mdiv.innerHTML = 'The card # has already been registered';
    document.getElementById('cardErrMsg').innerHTML = arrowGif;
```

}

I've stepped through this in FireBug and I've seen it fail to test this string:

```
> Error: <detail>Card number already registered for CLP.\n</detail>
```

Am I missing something? What is the likely issue with this?

Comment: `.` will *not* match a newline by default. Also, " " is likely better written as "\s+"

Comment: Not sure if related, but it looks like your javascript has a typo on the line with mdiv.innerHTML = ...

Comment: I also concur with pst.  I'm not sure why you even have the ^.* and .*$ bits anyway unless that's some reminder to anchor to the beginning and end when the whole string needs to match something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simplified but functionally-equivalent regex that should handle newlines:

`/(already\s+(active|exists|registered))/i`

Not sure why you'd ever want to lead with `^.*` or end with `.*$` unless your goal is specifically to prevent newlines. Otherwise it's just superfluous.

**EDIT:** I replaced the space with `\s+` so it will be more liberal with how it handles whitespace (e.g. one space, two spaces, a tab, etc. should all match).

Answer (score 2):

**tldr;** Use the `m` modifier to make `.` match newlines. See the [MDC regular expression documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Failing (note the "\n" in the string literal):

```
var str = "Error: <detail>Card number already registered for CLP.\n</detail>"
str.match(/^.*(already (active|exists|registered)).*$/i)
```

Working (note `m` flag for "multi-line" behavior of `.`):

```
var str = "Error: <detail>Card number already registered for CLP.\n</detail>"
str.match(/^.*(already (active|exists|registered)).*$/mi)
```

I would use a simpler form, however: (Adjust for definition of "space".)

```
var str = "Error: <detail>Card number already registered for CLP.\n</detail>";
str.match(/(?:already\s+(?:active|exists|registered))/i)
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I didn't realize that the newline would cause other problems